# If translation of function is smooth then function is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Recall that we write $\tau_t\varphi(x) = \varphi(x-t)$.

I want to show that if $t\mapsto\tau_t\varphi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a smooth map then $\varphi$ is smooth.

I tried to use mollifier but I don't see how it can be useful.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah I see. So $\Bbb R\ni t\mapsto\tau_t\varphi\in\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega)$ is considered smooth in the sense of being infinitely Frechet differentiable with the usual metric structure on $\mathcal{L}^2$?

Comment: Wait. Since the codomain is changing with $t$, how can differentiation even be sensibly defined?

Comment: @FShrike Maybe it's better to take the whole space ?

Comment: The whole space of what? It seems to me the hypothesis can only make sense if $\Omega=\Bbb R^n$ as then $\Omega+t=\Omega$ always. In any case this needs more context

Comment: @AnneBauval no because I changed the hypothesis and now $\varphi$ is defined on unbounded set

Comment: By applying the Fourier transform the problem is equivalent to smoothness of the mapping $t\mapsto e^{itx}\hat{f}(x).$ The mapping is smooth iff  $x^n\hat{f}(x)\in L^2$ for any $n.$

Answer (score 3):

By applying the Fourier transform (which is an isometric isomorphism of  $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ onto itself) we get $$\widehat{\tau_tf}(\lambda)=e^{-2\pi i\langle t,\lambda\rangle }\widehat{f}(\lambda),\quad \lambda\in \mathbb{R}^n\quad(1)$$ The mapping $t\mapsto \tau_tf$ is smooth if and only if the mapping $t\mapsto \widehat{\tau_tf}$ is smooth.

For simplicity of the presentation we will restrict to the case $n=1.$
The mapping $(1)$ is of the form
$$F_t(\lambda)=h(t,\lambda)g(\lambda),$$ where $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}),$ $h(t,\lambda)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $|h(t,\lambda)|\le 1.$
Assume $t\mapsto F_t$ is differentiable. Then
$$\left ({d\over dt}F_t\right )(\lambda)={\partial \over \partial t}h(t,\lambda)\,g(\lambda)\qquad (2)$$ Indeed,  fix $\delta_n\searrow 0.$ By assumptions the sequence
$${F(t+\delta_n)-F(t)\over \delta_n}\quad\qquad \qquad \quad(3)$$ is convergent in $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Therefore it contains a subsequence convergent almost everywhere. With no loss of generality we may assume that the sequence in $(3)$ is convergent almost everywhere. Clearly $(2)$ holds for the pointwise derivative, which concludes the proof of $(2).$

In the OP case we have $F_t(\lambda)=e^{-2\pi it\lambda}g(\lambda)$ for $g=\widehat{f}.$ Thus
$$\left ({d\over dt}F_t\right )(\lambda)=-2\pi i\lambda e^{-2\pi it\lambda}g(\lambda)$$
This implies $\lambda g(\lambda)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

By iterating the same procedure for higher derivatives of $F_t$ we obtain that $\lambda^ng(\lambda)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for any $n,$ i.e. $\lambda^n\widehat{f}(\lambda)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for any $n.$ By the Fourier inversion formula we obtain that the function $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Why does the Fourier inversions formula prove that, say, if $x\hat{f}(x)$ is integrable then $f$ is differentiable (everywhere)?

Comment: It follows from the fact that if $g(x)$ and $xg(x)$ are absolutely integrable then $\widehat{g}$ is continuously differentiable. In our case we apply that to the function $g=\widehat{f}$ and use the Fourier inversion formula [see for example](https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math262/Lectures/Lecture02.pdf) Perhaps some stronger properties are needed, but they are satisfied as in our case we know that $x^n\widehat{f}(x)$ is integrable for any $n.$

Comment: I now understand your point, thanks

Comment: Concerning your deleted comment, there is a general theorem that if $k(x,y)$ and ${\partial \over \partial x}k(x,y)$ are uniformly (with respect to $x$) integrable with respect to $y$ then the function $h(x)=\int k(x,y)\,dy$ is differentiable and $h'(x)=\int {\partial k\over \partial x}(x,y)\,dy.$ I hope the assumptions are correct.